Cannot run apk (or other https calls) inside of docker container hosted in Windows WSL2 (Debian)
Ultimately trying to build a docker container based on alpine. Using wsl+docker desktop on Windows.
It looks like the container cannot make https calls. e.g.
C:\Users\me\dev\foo\demo-app>docker run -it amazoncorretto:21-alpine /bin/sh
/ # apk update
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: updating and opening https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main: Permission denied
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: updating and opening https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/community: Permission denied
fetch https://apk.corretto.aws/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: updating and opening https://apk.corretto.aws: could not connect to server (check repositories file)
6 unavailable, 0 stale; 17 distinct packages available
/ #

I can fetch this w/curl from within windows itself.
C:\Users\me\dev\foo\demo-app>curl -o windows_cmd.tgz https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  456k  100  456k    0     0   728k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  732k

Inside of the default linux distro, I have set environment vars for http proxy, and also copied/installed the ZScaler certificate, and it works.
 C:\Users\me\dev\foo\demo-app>bash
me@USDSCWN34136453:/mnt/c/Users/me/dev/foo/demo-app$ curl -o wsl_bash.tgz https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  456k  100  456k    0     0  1040k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1039k

I assume that the docker-run container does not know about the ZScaler cert, and is ok in terms of dns and proxies. It's hard to tell though as alpine doesn't come with nice things like curl by default.
Assuming it's the certificate, how do I get windows-docker to pass that on to the container? If you don't think it's the certificate, what suggestions do you have?
update: Adding the zscaler cert per this answer has no effect.

Can you openssl s_client -connect dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org:443 from inside the container? Or maybe just nc -zv dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org 443 to rule out Docker networking configuration issues ?

openssl is not installed, and nc -zv dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org 443 exits with a status of 1 and produces no output.

Then you have a networking problem. You might also have a certificate problem, but you haven't reached that part yet. I'll see if I can reproduce on my Windows box, and post an answer if I find something.

@ixe013 yes, I think you're right.

What Docker are you running? It is strange that you mention WSL2, but you run the docker command from a Windows prompt. Works out of the box for me with Docker Desktop for Windows version v4.33.1. Run  where docker and run your command again with the full path to your Windows docker installation, something like "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe" run -it amazoncorretto:21-alpine /bin/sh
